# dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Tags: mysql, osx-elcapitan

After upgrading Mac OS X to El Capitan, I got:

> dyld: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib

trying:

> `sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`

I got:

> ln: /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

> sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Comment: ```sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```
# => ln: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib: File exists

Answer (score 9):

In my case, using MySQL Workbench app, the dylib file needed to exists in the Framework folder inside the application folder, so I needed to run:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libmysqlclient.21.dylib /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Frameworks/libmysqlclient.dylib
```

Comment: Same fix required with MySQLWorkbench 8.0.34